# How to set up an OpenID Connect client in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, openid-connect

What is the best way to get an OpenID Connect client flow going in the PHP Laravel framework? I have looked at socialite but that does not support OpenID Connect.

Comment: Did you ever get any answer to this question?

Comment: @ihue I ended up doing the flow myself, the lib I used in the end was https://github.com/jumbojett/OpenID-Connect-PHP - was a nice and simple to get up and running

Comment: @WilburRobertson please post answer to your question

Comment: can you elaborate a little bit more that how to use it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up doing the flow myself, the lib I used in the end was https://github.com/jumbojett/OpenID-Connect-PHP - was a nice and simple to get up and running

Comment: Can you share how you did the flow? I try to make a flow with ZITADEL but I have not been able to do it.